# Gear VR Framework Override Back Button Functionality

Tags: android, back-button, virtual-reality, oculus, gear-vr

We are developing a Gear VR Application using GVRf. There are two GVRScenes in the app, and we want it such that if the user short presses back button in scene B it goes back to scene A, and if the user short presses back button in scene A it exits the app. Also, long pressing the back button should show the Oculus settings menu, and pressing back from that should resume the app(according to Oculus store requirements).

Since `GVRActivity.onBackPressed()` is not called from the framework, we tried to override the `onKeyUp` from `GVRActivity`:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK == keyCode) {
        if (mScript.onBackPressed()) {//mScript.onBackPressed() handles change scene logic 
                                      //and returns true if we are in scene B, and returns  
                                      //false if we are in scene A
             super.onBackPressed();
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

Right now short press from scene B is ok, and long press is showing the oculus settings. The problem is that if we press back from scene B and press back from settings, it switches to scene A, and if we do the same from scene A the app restarts.

What is the correct way to implement this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found a work-around for this.

First, modify `GVRActivity`'s `mPaused` to `protected`.

```
    protected boolean mPaused = true;
```

And then we added overrode the `onKeyUp()` in our `Activity`:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onKeyUp: "+keyCode);
    if(!mPaused && keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
        if(!mScript.onBackPressed())
            return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

Hope this can help someone else, if anyone has a better solution, feel free to post it.